# R converting a string into an integer within a data frame

Tags: r

```
REF         ALT 
 AT  ATT,A,ATTT
```

I'm working with the data frame above and need to convert the `REF` column containing just `AT` into an integer of `0` and then the `ALT` column containing `ATT,A,ATTT` into `1,2,3`, I have tried Transform but it didn't seem to work.

Also my full data frame has multiple rows so I would need to loop the command to apply to all rows.

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: It is not clear what exactly is in the other rows of your "full data frame". Can you give a few more rows, and then an example of what you want them converted into? The question as it now stands cannot be answered.

Comment: Do you have a prespecified idea of which items should have which numbers? Or is it just about doing them consecutively? If ATTT appears again should it be 3 again or a different number?

Comment: The other rows will have the same format at above, the REF column will always only have one value in. The ALT column will vary one the number of values it contains. It's just about them consecutively so  if the ALT row contains  AT,A it would become 1,2     ATT,AAA,ATTT  would become 1,2,3  and if theres only one just 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setting the `REF` column to 0 is straightforward.

```
df$REF <- 0
```

For the `ALT` column I assume that order for each entry matters but rows are independent. So an `A` could be numbered 1 in one row but 2 in another (if there are multiple entries in that row). So the only thing we care about is the number of alternatives in each row. We can simply count them and generate a vector with the appropriate numbers, collapsing them into a single string to form the corresponding entry in the data frame:

```
df$ALT <- sapply(strsplit(df$ALT, ","), 
    function(alt) paste(1:length(alt), collapse=","))
```

Answer (score 0):

Loop in R is really inefficient so I would strongly advise against it if it is not absolutely necessary and in your case I don't think that it is necessary.

for example you can do, (assuming your dataframe is called "df"):

```
df$REF<-0 # from what I gather all rows should be 0


df$ALT2<-1 # a proxy column that you can copy to ALT after
df$ALT2[df$ALT == "A"] <-2 # converts A to 2
df$ALT2[df$ALT == "ATTT"] <-3 # converts ATTT to 2

df$ALT<-df$ALT2 # copy proxy over to ALT
df$ALT2<-NULL #erase proxy column
```

If you don't care which character string gets assigned to which number, but you just want different strings to have a different intetger, you can also do:

```
df$REF<-0 # from what I gather all rows should be 0
df$ALT <- as.numeric(factor(df$ALT)) # give a distinct number to each distinct string counting up from 1.
```